# Reviewing Close Votes: Leave Open Vs Skip

Tags: support

I'm a new member of the 3k+ club.

Does clicking **leave open** do anything? It appears to me that it's the same as hitting **skip**.

I was hoping the **leave open** would veto/cancel a close vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Leave open means you evaluated the question, and think it should stay open
- Skip means you don't feel competent to evaluate - good choice, actually, if for any reason you feel unsure.

If question earns significantly more "leave open" votes than close votes, it falls from the review queue. Only people who stumble upon that question naturally will then see it and might vote. Then, if no people vote for some time, close votes just age away.

[There was a network-wide request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234302/225745) for "leave open" votes to remove close votes, but it was not well received, and for good reasons.